# Arithmetic and Relational Operators

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I followed my book to the T and for some reason when I try and run my program I get completely wrong output for the operator- and the operator+ for my output. Do you know what is going wrong with my Overloaded operator- and my overloaded operator+. The program compiles fine but the output is not right at all.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class NumDays
    {
    private:
    int ptrHours;
    public:
    NumDays(int H)// to set the pointer
    { setHours(H);}
    void setHours(int H)
    {ptrHours = H;}
    int gethours()  {return ptrHours;}

    double calcDays()// function to calculate the days
    {
    double days;
    days = ptrHours/8.0;
    return days;
    }
    friend NumDays operator+(NumDays a, NumDays b);
    friend NumDays operator-(NumDays a, NumDays b);

    };

    NumDays operator+(NumDays a, NumDays b)
    {
    return NumDays(a.ptrHours + b.ptrHours);
    }
    NumDays operator-(NumDays a, NumDays b)
    {
    return (a.ptrHours - b.ptrHours);   
    }


int main ()
{
    NumDays first(0),
        second(0), 
        third(0);
    int hours1, hours2;
    cout <<"Enter the how many hours you worked..." << endl;
    cout <<"First set:  ";
        cin >> hours1;
    while (hours1 < 0)
    {
        cout <<"\nYou cannot enter a negative value. " << endl;;
            cin >> hours1;
    }
    first.setHours(hours1);
    cout <<"Second Set:  ";
        cin >> hours2;
    while (hours1 < 0)
    {
        cout <<"\nYou cannot enter a negative value. " << endl;;
            cin >> hours2;
    }
    second.setHours(hours2);
    cout <<"First set for days worked is " << first.calcDays() <<" days." <<      endl;
    cout <<"Second set for days worked is " << second.calcDays() <<" days." <<    endl;
    third = first - second;// where I try and do my arithmetic operators
    cout <<"First - Second = " << cout << third.gethours() << endl;
    third = first + second;
    cout <<"First + Second = " << cout << third.gethours() << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What output do you get, and what did you expect? Please edit your question to include that (copy-paste the actual output into the question body).

Comment: Formatting, please. Also, [should not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb217e190d2df2ff).

Comment: Also, remove the parts of the example, that are not needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: On a totally unrelated issue, the name `ptrHours` is kind of misleading, as `ptr` is usually an abbreviation of pointer, and the variable is definitely not a pointer.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Comment: This doesn't compile at all unless you've added an overload of `<<` for `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code.

```
cout <<"First + Second = " << cout << third.gethours() << endl;
```

You shouldn't use cout inside a cout. Your print statement should be like this

```
cout <<"First + Second = " << third.gethours() << endl;
```

Hope this will help. 
Thank you.